# Password : Unable to type password for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, passwords

I am using PostgreSQL version 10 on Windows 10, and trying to create a new Database, but from Windows Command prompt, I could not enter a password.

I added path to environment and tried, but still its the same.

-

No input is taken by the system, On a forceful Enter, there is a Fatal Error: No input is taken by the system.

Comment: What error are you getting?  How are you connecting?

Comment: Are you connecting with the psql client? If so, with which arguments are you calling it?